# Xml loaded without values

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing, mini-xml

I have xml.xml file:

```
<root>Root
    <pai>Pai_1
        <filho>Pai1,Filho1</filho>
        <filho>Pai1,Filho2</filho>
    </pai>
    <pai>Pai_2
        <filho>Pai2,Filho1</filho>
        <filho>Pai2,Filho2</filho>
    </pai>
</root>
```

This file is loaded and then saved.

```
FILE *fp;
 mxml_node_t *tree;

    fp = fopen("xml.xml", "r");
    tree = mxmlLoadFile(NULL, fp, MXML_NO_CALLBACK);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("xmlout.xml", "w");
    mxmlSaveFile(tree, fp, MXML_NO_CALLBACK);
    fclose(fp);
```

On xmlout.xml I have:

```
<root>
    <pai>
        <filho /><filho />
    </pai>
    <pai>
        <filho /><filho />
    </pai>
</root>
```

Where are values?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in mini-xml 2.8 handling of `mxmlLoadFd()`  `MXML_NO_CALLBACK/MXML_TEXT_CALLBACK` that loses text nodes.

See minixml bug 502 for details.

As a workaround,  define your own text callback, and pass that to `mxmlLoadFd` instead.